# Cloned repo won't commit along with parent repo (root)

Tags: git

I've cloned react-headroom into a lib folder of my next.js project, so I could change the source and make it behave like I need. However, VSCode builtin git tool won't commit these changes in that subrepo.

I'd like to understand how can I deal with such situation. My changes to react-headroom are really customizations for my project and I see no reason for a pull request. Maybe I should detach this lib/react-headroom from it's original git repo in order to operate like I want to but I'm a bit insecure on how should I do it.

Comment: You probably want to make a [fork](https://docs.github.com/en/get-started/quickstart/fork-a-repo) of the repo

Comment: To second what @joshmeranda said, fork the original repo, make your changes and commit to your git host (i.e. github.com or the like). Then add the forked version of the code as a dependency using the following: `https://github.com/user_name/node_project_name` where `user_name` is your _user name_ and `node_project_name` would be your fork name, presumably _react-headroom_. And again, this is provided you're using github.com as your repo store. You'd need to change it to use your repo host if you're using something else.